# webRTC audio - Don't know how to resume streaming after closing/stoping it

Tags: javascript, django, audio, webrtc, streaming

I was trying webRTC for a chatbot with voice prompts. I was successful on incorporating the voice prompts to the chat, but i have a problem. I noticed the mediaRecorder.stop doesn't stop the streaming, so the red circle in the window will not dissapear. I want it to only be streaming when the user is recording the message.

What i tried:
I searched other solutions and found that this line will successfully end the streaming:
`stream.getTracks().forEach( track => track.stop() );`

The problem is, I don't know how to resume the streaming after that, the record button turns unresponsive.

This is my entire code, sorry for not providing a more compact one, i'm not too keen with javascript to leave things behind:

```
  let mediaRecorder;
  let recordedChunks = [];
  let isRecording = false; // Track the recording state

  // Function to start recording
  function startRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') {
      mediaRecorder.start();
      isRecording = true;
    }
  }

  // Function to stop recording
  function stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      isRecording = false;
    }
  }
  // Function to initialize the MediaRecorder
  function initializeMediaRecorder() {
    if (!mediaRecorder) {
      // Initialize the MediaRecorder with audio constraints
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

          // Add data to the recordedChunks array when data is available
          mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
            if (e.data.size > 0) {
              recordedChunks.push(e.data);
            }
          };

          // When the recording is stopped, you can process the recorded data
          mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
            const audioBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
            const audioSize = audioBlob.size;
            recordedChunks = [];

            // Example: Send the audio data to the server or do something else with it
            const messageItem = document.createElement('li');
            messageItem.classList.add('message', 'sent');
            messageItem.innerHTML = `
                <div class="message-text">
                    <div class="message-sender">
                        <b>You</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="message-content">
                        Audio size: ${audioSize}. Recording state: ${mediaRecorder.state}
                    </div>
                </div>`;
            messagesList.appendChild(messageItem);
            //stream.getTracks().forEach( track => track.stop() );
          };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error accessing audio:', error);
        });
    }
  }

  // Attach click event handler to the "Record" button
  const recordButton = document.querySelector('.btn-record');
  recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!isRecording) {
      // Start recording
      startRecording();
      initializeMediaRecorder(); // Initialize the MediaRecorder 

    } else {
      // Stop recording
      stopRecording();
    }
  });
```

I know some conditions are redundant, i was debugging.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to reuse MediaRecorder - just create a new one, this is the simplest solution. Set `mediaRecorder = null` after `mediaRecorder.stop();` and it will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Although, i had to set the mediaRecorder null after stopping the tracks instead of stopping the mediaRecorder. This worked. By any chance do you know why the first click only starts the streaming and only after the second click it starts recording?

Comment: Just call `mediaRecorder.start();` AFTER creating mediaRecorder. Currently you have classical race condition:
* press "start", it's not "starting" as there is no mediaRecorder
* mediaRecorder is created in initializeMediaRecorder
* press "start" again and it's really starting as mediaRecorder is here

Comment: Also:
* don't use separate variable `isRecording` - it's more accurate to use `mediaRecorder.state`.
* call `initializeMediaRecorder()` from `startRecording()` - this will avoid cases when `mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive'` is false, but it tries to start the recording.

Comment: Yes, all those conditions were there because i was debugging, trying to find where is something wrong. Thank you